# Upgrading Libzip in MAMP Windows 10

Tags: php, mamp, zip, libzip

How can I upgrade to the latest version of libzip on a Windows 10 machine running MAMP 4.0?

I haven't a clue where to start and have trawled the web for advice. Compiling means little to me as I don't know where to begin.

I'm trying to use ZipFile() encryption using php and it comes up with an error Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ZipArchive::setEncryptionName(). Google says to update libZip to latest version and it will work but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by upgrading to MAMP version 4.0.1. Any feedback as to how to individually upgrade libzip would be welcome, though.